# Cannot download JD-Eclipse from site? Any other download sources?

Tags: java, decompiler

Working on a backup laptop that doesn't have JD decompiler installed.
Went to the site to download (http://java.decompiler.free.fr) but the download links now appear to reference a Google Drive location and the error message below keeps coming up.

I'll certainly be making sure I don't share anything from GD publicly, didn't realise there were limits. In the meantime does anybody know where else I can get the software?

Error:

> Sorry, you can't view or download this file at this time.
>
> Too many users have viewed or downloaded this file recently. Please try accessing the file again later. If the file that you are trying to access is particularly large or is shared with many people, it may take up to 24 hours to be able to view or download the file. If you still can't access a file after 24 hours, contact your domain administrator.

Comment: Apologies, this is off topic. Please read the FAQ before asking questions.

Comment: I disagree it is off topic - the FAQ says "software tools commonly used by programmers". JD is such a tool - and it is a massive community problem if the author can no longer distribute it on his site given the only viable free alternative has been unmaintained for a long while ....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can no longer store JD-GUI and JD-Eclipse binary files on free.fr. Any suggestions to store them elsewhere ?

In the short term, try this link : http://web.archive.org/web/20110720221237/http://java.decompiler.free.fr/jd-eclipse/update/jdeclipse_update_site.zip

[EDIT]
I fear that "java.decompiler.free.fr" is definitely closed. Try this link : http://jd.benow.ca/jd-eclipse/downloads/jdeclipse_update_site.zip
[/EDIT]

Comment: Ah - tricky! Not sure from a free storage perspective - other than a free dropbox account maybe. Amazon S3 would only cost 12.5 cents for a GB/month? Happy to make a contribution if you can figure out how to get it to me in the next hour or so - really struggling without it!!! :-) Also - well done on creating a brilliantly useful tool.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate link - much appreciated!

Comment: I'm hosting JD-Eclipse on my update site linked from my blog: http://mchr3k-coding.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/realignment-for-jd-eclipse.html. I am using Google App Engine to host the update site for free with 1GB of transfer/day free.

Comment: You can use DropBox or I can host it in my site http://venomvendor.com/ i have unlimited Space & BW, btw thanks for the wonderful De compiler.

Comment: Any news on this ? Your site http://java.decompiler.free.fr/ is down !

Comment: I know. My apologies for the inconvenience. Try http://jd.benow.ca

Comment: Thanks - delete the comments and edit your question with these links - I will delete mine once you do this. Also always add @<user> if you want <user to be notified of your comment - I saw this accidentally

Comment: I would also suggest searching a bit on strackoverflow and editing couple posts - all links point to your old site and this harms you !

Comment: I've updated my answer in a related question to reflect this update: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371451/jd-decompiler-for-eclipse-4-2-juno/12261136#12261136. Thanks.